# How to choose ipad application in ios?

Tags: ios, ipad, uistoryboard

I am working on an ipad Application.
I choose ipad target for project.
But i am not getting option of ipad different screen size in Attribute inspector.
Problem is attached in screenshot.

please help me to find out an issue.

[image: My target]

[image: Plase Check]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to enable `Use Size Classe` from xib/storyboard.

[image]

Once you enable size classes then xib/storyboard is compatible with universal app after that you can disable size classes then xcode display on popup for choose size classes then xib/storyboard will convert in particular size classes (iPhone/iPad).

[image]

Comment: @KrutarthPatel, You can accept my answer if you are satisfied with answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just enable size class, and if you don't want to use size class, just disable it. At that time you will get a option to select iPhone or iPad. Select iPad. Your done.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling size classes

Select the storyboard in the Project navigator. Use the File inspector and enable Size Classes. That solves it.

Without Enabling size classes

Disable Size Classes again but when the dialog appears, specify that you want to keep the iPad size class data.

Comment: @KrutarthPatel anytime :)

Comment: i want to get information of size class.have you any link why it is usefull

Comment: @KrutarthPatel check this link : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html

Comment: if i am developing only ipad application. no need of size class is ok?

Comment: @KrutarthPatel if you do not use size classe you need to set auto layout or else you can set constraints. Do as per your convenience !!

Comment: @KrutarthPatel your welcome...you can accept my answer if you are satisfied :)

Comment: i have accept answer of jayesh.is it possible to accept two answers?

Comment: @KrutarthPatel no its not possible but its fine.let it be (y)